# Open form as form.ShowDialog() and proceed wih function in parent form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an application where the users can add or delete products in a dashboard, because I connect it to azure sql the queries sometimes take time, so I need to block the ui in the main form, I tried disabling the currently open form. but that make the ui look bad.. I also tried form.ShowDialog() which made the main ui struck.. how can I block the main UI till the query is completed?

Comment: Can you please show some minimum code to explain what you have tried so far, which part is getting struck. There are few options, one of them is you can try  using splash screen to show wait form and close when your query is completed.

Comment: You can load query in sync mode (if data provider has such a method). Loading will be made in UI thread and will be blocking user interactions. But as @Mdyahiya mention, splashscreen with some progress bar is better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A sample "Please Wait" form with.
Here there is two form
1. Main Form with a `Button`
2. Form Designed to show as "Please wait" message. The Form contains two control 
    a. **Label**
    b. **Progress Bar** - the property `style` for the progress bar is made as `Marquee`

[image: Sample Image]

1. PleaseWait.cs

   ```
   public partial class PleaseWait : Form
   {
       public Action Worker { get; set; }
       public PleaseWait(Action worker)
       {
           InitializeComponent();

           if(worker == null)
               throw new ArgumentNullException();

           Worker = worker;
       }

       protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
       {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            Task.Factory.StartNew(Worker).ContinueWith(a=> 
            {
                this.Close();
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
       }
   }
   ```
2. MainForm.cs . In `button1_click` you will initialize the `PleaseWait` Form as `ShowDialog`

   ```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       using (PleaseWait pw = new PleaseWait(MakeAzureSQLQuery))
       {
           pw.ShowDialog();
       }
   }

   private void MakeAzureSQLQuery()
   {
       //Making the Query Function
       //You can also use Background Thread for Querying
       for (int nCount = 0; nCount < 500; nCount++)
           Thread.Sleep(50);
   }
   ```